# Webpack/Typescript alias relative import to node module

Tags: typescript, webpack, babeljs

I think this should be a relatively easy question, how does one alias a relative import to one that is in node_modules?

Specifically, I want something like this:

```js
import SomeModule from './thing/some-module'
```

to translate to actually importing from `node_modules` `module-thing/some-module`. Bonus points if the method can also change `module-thing/some-module` to like `module-thing/some-other-module`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
 resolve: {
  alias: {
    'thing/some-module'': path.resolve(__dirname, 'module-thing/some-module'),
  },
}
```

You can try something like this in you Webpack config, please take this as a reference you might have to do some trials based on your module paths.

please refer the docs for further details : https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolvealias

Comment: additionally you can add [paths](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#paths) in your tsconfig, for reference in your IDE. But i am not sure webpack picks up on that, so you may have to additionally write it in webpack config, as given in the answer.

Comment: These both may have missed my question, `module-thing` is in `node_modules`, pretty sure this doesn't work with that

Comment: @Jay works with node_modules too, just start with your package name.

Comment: @PrakashSaripaka this doesn't work with relative imports I believe. At least when I tried it it didn't